# How Can I use the SC command in a Batch to convert the Service Display Name to the Service Name?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two parameters that are passed bye a service monitoring system. They are the Service Display Name and Machine name. I found the SC command can retrieve the service name via the GetKeyName. I have searched this site and others for a week and I'm stuck with how to extract output from that data to convert to a Service Start Command when the system is notified that a service is down.

I am needing to create the batch/script so that is can receive the Service Display Name as a parameter, determine the Service Name then issue the start command. This seems simple enough but when looking at the FOR command and taking into account the unknown number of tokens possible when looking at the FOR option because some service display names have multiple space breaks.

I'm looking for a solution that crosses multiple Window 2008/2003 systems without having to code for each specific set of services on that server or building a script that searcher all services when just one is stopper because there are services that are stopped for a reason and should not be restarted. This is why we have a central monitoring system that is using the display name/server name.

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Generally, we expect to see some code that demonstrates that the asker is indeed trying at the problem on their own.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Assume that everything will be fine
    set "_exitCode=0"

    rem Retrieve the service display name from parameters to batch file
    rem If it contains spaces, "quote the service name"
    set "_serviceDN=%~1"

    rem Check parameters
    if "%_serviceDN%"=="" (
        echo ERROR: Usage is %~n0 "service display name"
        set "_exitCode=1"
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem Retrieve service name
    set "_serviceName="
    for /F "tokens=1,* delims== " %%a in (' sc GetKeyName "%_serviceDN%" ^| find "=" ') do (
        set "_serviceName=%%b"
    )

    rem Check if we have retrieved the service name. 
    if "%_serviceName%"=="" (
        echo ERROR: Service "%_serviceDN%" not found
        set "_exitCode=2"
        goto endProcess
    )

    rem Get service state
    set "_serviceState="
    for /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims=: " %%f in ('sc query "%_serviceName%" ^| find ":" ') do (
        if not defined _serviceState set "_serviceState=%%f"
    )

    rem Check if service is stopped and if necessary, start it
    if "%_serviceState%"=="STOPPED" (
        sc start "%_serviceName%" > nul 2>nul 
        set "_exitCode=!errorlevel!"
    )

:endProcess

    rem Clean and return exit code
    endlocal & exit /b %_exitCode%
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sc //machinename query | findstr DISPLAY_NAME | findstr service.name
```

Run from PowerShell